# error: cannot find symbol(JList, list.SetVisibleRowCount(int))

Tags: java, swing

I am getting this error:

```
randomproject.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
                list.SetVisibleRowCount(5);
                    ^
  symbol:   method SetVisibleRowCount(int)
  location: variable list of type JList<String>
1 error
```

I am not sure what the problem is, i was able to use that reference to the object when i needed to get the instance of  setSelectionMode, setSelectedIndex, addListSelectionListener, setLayoutOrientation, etc, methods.

Here is my code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(false); //subpanel
GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
panel.setLayout(gridbag);
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

listModel.addElement("element1");
listModel.addElement("element2");
listModel.addElement("element3");
listModel.addElement("element4");

JList list = new JList<>(listModel);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
list.setSelectedIndex(0);
list.addListSelectionListener(this);
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
list.SetVisibleRowCount(-1);
JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
listScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
panel.add(list);
```

Comment: Java is case sensitive. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a typo. you need to call  `setVisibleRowCount` and not `SetVisibleRowCount`
`s` should be **small**

Replace

`list.SetVisibleRowCount(-1);`

with

```
list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: You should really vote to close on these types of questions. They are not helpful in any way.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis correct